# Count rows per date in a date range

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have been searching Google and SO for the last 25 min searching for how to do the following in MySQL.

I currently have the following query (Sent by PHP):

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*),
    `$db`.`crop`.`id` AS `crop`,
    `$db`.`crop`.`harvest_date` AS `harvest_date`
FROM
    `$db`.`crop`
WHERE
    `$db`.`crop`.`harvest_date` BETWEEN $startDate AND $endDate
GROUP BY `$db`.`crop`.`harvest_date`

$startDate = 2012-01-01
$endDate = 2013-07-01
```

I am trying to find all the rows that have a harvest_date between start and end dates, and then count the number of rows that fall on the same date. However, I seem to be getting no results. The query doesn't fail, it just doesn't return anything. Can anyone point me in the right direction/tell me where I got it wrong?

EDIT: Found the problem. As Michael pointed out below, the dates were not getting passed as dates, but as numbers. I solved this by adding ' before and after startDate and endDate in the query.

Comment: The query should be failing. Your date literals need to be single-quoted strings. as in `$startDate = '2012-01-01'`

Comment: When you are grouping by `harvest_date` you have to use some kind of aggregate function (like, `min()`, `max()` or `group_concat()`) for `id`.

Comment: Which type is `harvest_date` ?

Comment: What would the value of `id` be, since several rows are supposed to be grouped together (by harvest date), and all rows, presumably, have a unique id? This query doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo harvest_date is a DATE

Comment: Wait, actually, MySQL isn't failing but is instead misinterpreting your unquoted dates as arithmetic!  `2012 - 1 - 1 = 2010` and `2013 - 7 - 1 = 2005` so `BETWEEN 2010 AND 2005` which is never met.

Comment: The id is not really used.

Comment: All fixed! I thank you very much @MichaelBerkowski.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Post as answer and ill accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL expects date literals to be single-quoted strings like `'2012-01-01'` and `'2013-07-01'`.

Since you have not quoted your date literals which are PHP variables, PHP is actually interpreting them as arithmetic on integer values before it passes them into the query.

```
// You see this:
$startDate = 2012-01-01
$endDate = 2013-07-01

// PHP does this:
// 2012 - 1 - 1 = 2010
$startDate = 2010
// 2013 - 7 - 1 = 2005
$endDate = 2005
```

Your query ultimately uses this:

```
WHERE
    `$db`.`crop`.`harvest_date` BETWEEN 2010 AND 2005
```

And MySQL will cast both of those integers to a `DATE`, which will return `NULL`.

```
mysql> SELECT CAST(2010 AS DATE);
+--------------------+
| CAST(2010 AS DATE) |
+--------------------+
| NULL               |
+--------------------+
```

So the simple fix is:

```
$startDate = '2012-01-01';
$endDate = '2013-07-01';
```

And if you eventually convert this to a parameterized query, the correct quoting of placeholders would be handled for you.

Answer (score 1):

To get the count between the given date range. Modify the query as

```
SELECT
   COUNT(`$db`.`crop`.`id`),
FROM
   `$db`.`crop`
WHERE
  `$db`.`crop`.`harvest_date` BETWEEN $startDate AND $endDate
```

Grouping the result with "harvest_date" will determine the count for that particular date and group them.

example :
if the table is like

8-21-2013

8-21-2013

8-20-2013

then grouping will give

2

1

without grouping

3

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post , but this worked for me

> SELECT count(*),date(LSTUPDTIM),SUM(TOTAL) FROM order_table where LSTUPDTIM between '2018-01-20' and '2019-01-29' group by date(LSTUPDTIM) ;

,

my LSTUPDTIM is a TimeStamp which is why i had to use date()
which gave me an output like this

5   2019-01-25  500

2   2019-01-28  200

5   2019-01-29  500